# Did Anakin modify R2-D2, or do all R2 units come with crazy gadgets?

Tags: star-wars, droids, r2-d2

R2-D2 has jet boosters, a buzz saw, an oil gun, and all sorts of exciting weaponry.

Is this default equipment for an astromech droid? Or did Anakin (or someone else) modify R2-D2?

Comment: He only has a zapper. No other weaponry. And I suspect that's a welding tool

Comment: [He has a buzzsaw](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Buzz_saw) and [an oil gun](https://youtu.be/jXTGzKkTTLk?t=54). He also has a cable gun, which we see when he drags C-3P0's head behind him at the Battle of Geonosis.

Comment: None of it is weaponry, just tools utilised as weapons.

Comment: Did someone tweak R2's programming to make it more effective at using tools as weapons / understanding combat? Or does default astromech droid programming include that stuff? Or has the droid just learned and improved over time?

Comment: R2 has certainly learned over time, it's mentioned quite a lot how because he's lived so long with no memory wipes he has his own personality and initiative which he uses to his advantage to save the day on occasions.

Comment: The R2 Series of droids is blessed with dozens of tools as standard. You can also load it out with hundreds of custom parts.

Comment: Standard practice in both legends and current canon is for droid memories to be wiped fairly regularly, partly to prevent them from storing up classified information and partly to keep them from developing certain..eccentricities but R2 has instead been allowed to become 4 feet of solid sass.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Star Wars: Blueprints - The Ultimate Collection](https://starwars.fandom.com/nl/wiki/Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection) factbook, the standard loadout for an R2 unit includes two manipulator arms, an electric arc welder (which Artoo periodically uses as an ersatz stun-gun), a holo-projector, a circular saw, a fire extinguisher and an internal cargo area. This would suggest that a lot of the tools we see in the Original Trilogy are stock items.

[image]